# Scheduled Executor Service is only running once, no exceptions are thrown

Tags: java, android, scheduledexecutorservice

This code should run indefinitely. However, it successfully runs once and then never again. No exceptions are throw so I can't figure out what I did wrong. However, when nextExpression is not called, it does run indefinitely.

Here is the code:

```
onCreate() {

    Runnable Runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
            nextExpression();
        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


int i = 0;

public void nextExpression() {
    i++;
    expression.setText("" + i);
}
```

Comment: Which is the `expression` type and what does `setText` implementation contain?

Comment: expression type is a textView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested and it runs as it should, if you want to update a UI component you should do it with the main thread.

To update the textView from the Main thread you can do it like this:

```
public void nextExpression() {
    i++;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            expression.setText("" + i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your UI update is not happening on UI thread but on threadpool thread, that won't work. To relay update to UI thread modify

```
expression.setText("" + i);
```

to

```
expression.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                expression.setText("" + i);
            }
        });
```